# How does one lookup a ID based on a choice form in a jenkins scripted pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, input, dropdownchoice

I have a puzzle for you!

I am trying to create a choice parameter from in jenkins to prompt for items to download from sharepoint.Hoever, I can seem to get the id value from a list that contains multiple items....

code

```
def teamList = [
    [name: 'Select', id: null],
    [name: 'team1', id: 'teamcred1'],
    [name: 'team2', id: 'teamcred2'],
]

... 
 
stage('Get: info') {
    getStuff(teamList)
}

...

def getStuff(teamList) {
    script {
       def infoIn = input(
          id: 'in', message: 'What file?', ok: 'Select',
              parameters: [
                   string(defaultValue: '',
                      description: 'File name',
                      name: 'file'),
                   string(defaultValue: '',
                      description: 'Path ?',
                      name: 'path'),
                  [$class: 'ChoiceParameterDefinition', 
                      name: 'team', 
                      choices: teamList.name as List, 
                      description: 'Teams '],
       ])

       selectedTeam = teamList.find{it.name == infoIn.name}.id
       # def inputTeam = infoIn.name?:'' 
       def inputPath = infoIn.path?:'Documents'
       def inputFile = infoIn.file?:''
       echo "Team: ${inputTeam}"

       echo "file: ${inputFile}"
       echo "Path: ${inputPath}"
       echo "Team: ${inputTeam}" 
...
```

and the error:

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'id' on null object
```

Why can't I get the id value from the team list when I have more than one input entry? the prompt for information seen in the pipeline works fine, and we have the dropdown with the team list names.... But, when I try to get the id, it fails and  if I ask for only the team and forget about the file and path in the input block, it works fine? why is that?

Ta,

X